# Tagged-only VLANs

Tags: vlan, networking, hp-procurve

I have an HP ProCurve swicth configured as follows (simplified, with U for Untagged and T for Tagged):

**VLAN_1:**

```
U 1,3,5,7-10,12-16
T 2,4,6
No U 11
```

**VLAN_2:**

```
T 1,3,5
```

**VLAN_3:**

```
T 1,3,5
```

What is the purpose of a vlan containing *only* tagged ports?

What is the purpose of 2 identical vlan like VLAN_2 and VLAN_3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the purpose of a vlan containing only tagged ports?

Likely, those (trunk) ports interconnect VLANs spanning multiple switches. It's also possible that a trunk leads to a VLAN-aware host or a router.

> What is the purpose of 2 identichal vlan like VLAN_2 and VLAN_3?

VLANs separate layer-2 traffic. VLANs can look similar but may be used for entirely different purposes. Generally, VLAN should be properly *named* to document that.

Comment: Ah.. didn't think about vlan aware things.. and yes, multi-switch vlans.. thanks

Comment: The most general use case of vlans is quite simple. Affect ports to different vlans and designate as trunks those used to interconnect switches and/or vlan-aware hosts. But some switch vendors complicate things (probably for more flexibility) the configuration task by introducing notions like ingress vlan egress vlan, tagged/untagged port ...etc. All these can confuse even a skilled network admin

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar Mostly true, but tagging is generally required for trunk ports.

Comment: @Zac67 I know but it's more simpler to configure a port as trunk by a single command and then eventually forbid/allow some vlans on it (if there is a need) than a bunch of commands that are error prone. Network admin's life is already complicated, no need to add on that

Comment: Yes, `switchport mode trunk` is easy, but Procurves/HPE Provision/Aruba don't do it that way. They require explicit *tagged/untagged* configuration (which I actually find more transparent) or GVRP/MVRP.